# Why is GFCI Receptacle Tripping From Downstream Fluorescent LIght on Switch?

Tags: electrical, gfci

I recently ran power to a small shed in my backyard.  I extended a 15amp circuit that was powering only a gate motor.  The #12 wire enters the shed and transitions to 14/2 Romex at a disconnect.  The circuit is very simple: it feeds a GFCI receptacle (first image) then passes to a single pole light switch (second image) that switches hot wire to a standard receptacle with a fluorescent shop light plugged in (third image).

Everything is wired properly and works fine, except the fluorescent shop light plugged into the standard receptacle at the end of the circuit causes the GFCI to trip when turned off (most of the time).  I have tried plugging the light directly to the GFCI with no problems.  I have tried replacing the shop light with a small 60 watt light with no problem. I have tried replacing the shop light with a small air compressor with no problem. It seems to be this shop light causing it to trip when plugged into an outlet downstream of the GFCI.  I'm at a loss on what to try.  Could it be a bad GFCI?  Why is it only this scenario causing it to trip?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You did split the neutral on the GFCI.... right??  line and load?

Comment: Excuse my ignorance: What do you mean by "split the neutral"?

Comment: There is a separate connection for the line side and the load side of a GFCI outlet. You have your hot and neutral from your panel going into the line terminals on the GFCI outlet. Then you have your hot and neutral going from the load terminals of the GFCI to your switch. They have to be separated from the line.   Your neutral is split through the GFCI.

Comment: Ahh, yes, I have the GFCI wired properly.

Comment: Well, I don't agree that just slapping *everything* on LOAD is the way to go.  In my opinion LOAD should never be used unless it is your actual intention to extend GFCI protection to the things you are connecting to LOAD. That notwithstanding, I have faith that OP did wire it all correctly, because it passes all reasonable tests. This is indeed a weird one.

Comment: Sometimes some components have higher leakage to ground. I would try a different fluorescent fixture or see if you pull the plug while it is on if anything happens, my guess it is something in the electronic ballast that when powering down is dumping the stored charge in the caps to ground over 5 ma on the ground would cause this.

Comment: Yeah, I'm kinda embarrassed, I'm a big "modern T8  fluorescent" promoter, and normally they're better behaved than that.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Wouldn't all outlets in a shed have to be GFCI protected? If so, he'd have to slap everything on LOAD unless he hard wired the light.

Comment: As a side note: you extended 12 gauge wire with 14. Are you sure this is on a 15 amp breaker? If the breaker is 20 amps, the 12 gauge wire would be legal but the 14 would not.

Comment: I used #12 for the 80' run to reduce voltage loss.  It's definitely a 15amp breaker.  The wire to the gate motor that i tapped off of is 14 gauge.

Comment: You extended 12 gauge wire with 14. Are you sure this is on a 15 amp breaker? If the breaker is 20 amps, the 12 gauge wire would be legal but the 14 would not. <-- this is a big safety problem.  If there was a short in the #14 it wouldn't necessarily trip a 20 A breaker.  15A breaker would trip.

Comment: @Inquisitor -- can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please?

Comment: Yes, I'll try to find time tomorrow.  To add to the mysteriousness, the GFCI does not trip when turning the light on and off by the cord.  Also, it seems that it does not trip if I slowly lower the switch arm, which is something most people would not normally do.  When I flip the switch quickly it trips about 90% of the time.  Could it be a faulty switch?

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is embarrassing, but hopefully it helps others in the same situation. I used an old 3-way switch I had lying around and I mistakenly connected the ground wire to the other switch terminal rather than the ground terminal. So when I switched it to the off position current was leaking to ground and tripping the GFCI.

I wired it correctly and it's all working as it should.

Comment: Thank you for posting this follow-up. - Too many OPs dump us as soon as they get what they want. They don't write, they don't call, we never even find out if they made their homes warm and bright or if they got electrocuted.